# Behavior of spark.read.csv with inferschema=True in case of multiple file loading

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am facing a difficulty(rather a strange result) while trying to load multiple csv files simultaneously into Spark by

```
df = spark.read.csv('/dir/*.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
df.printschema()
# Sale_Value  String(nullable=true)  # it should be Double/float
# Name String # Fine for all string columns
```

So basically all my integer and double column are converting into String Type, and i am expecting it to be double type, as i am passing inferschema parameter as true.

I checked my data and confirmed that there is no null value or any string value is there.

Strange thing is->

1. i read each file into separate dfs, df1=spark.read.csv(file1, inferSchema=True),
   df2=spark.read.csv(file2, inferSchema=True), then printing schema for each dataframes, All the schema are as expected(dpouble are coming double, string is string)
2. I started appending each separate dfs into single df like df = df1.union(df2), df= df.union(df2)..etc and checked printing df.printSchema(), then also all results are as expected...No issue in that.

So i am confused with the behavior with multiple file load in single load staement(*.csv).

IS there anything i am missing about inferSchema behavior. Please shed some light.

## Edit

My data is doubleQuote enclosed(to avoid splitting of records if comma found in fields), ex: "name","sale_target","sale_V","gender"....

I have 3 files out of that 2 of the files are quote-enclosed and one file is without quote-enclosed(that is the reason, I've faced this issue, i dropped the file not having quotes in it, and guess what everything worked perfectly).

So is it mandatory that if i am using/reading/loading multiple csv files then either i have to use all-files-QuoteEnclosed or all-file-without-QuoteEnclosed??

File location https://github.com/satya-panda/king-s-things

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example ?

Comment: I have tried your sample code with spark 2.2.0 and printSchema() works as expected (retrieves String, double and timestamp types correctly). Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @zencefill- i am using spark.2.2.1       eliasah- I have some confidential info in that file, i will share a link Soon after anonymization. And my data is doubleQuotes enclosed.

Comment: @eliasah: I have shared the git location of those files. plz check. https://github.com/satya-panda/king-s-things